# IDE to edit Tor source

Tags: source-code

What IDE can I use to edit Tor source code as a single project?  Can I use Eclipse with C/C++? I tried it with Eclipse but I get errors : "some type not dedined."
Which IDE is best to edit Tor source?

Comment: I use Eclipse. It's a little hit and miss but it mostly works.
Sometimes you just need to ignore the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to learn a new tool (e.g. an IDE) and a new code base at the same time. The best tool is the one you are most comfortable with.

If you are new to C, Wikipedia has a pretty [comprehensive comparison of C/C++ IDES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B) that you can use to best meet your needs and skill level.